# TypeError: 'Entry' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import ttk, simpledialog
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("Sorting and Searching Algorithm")
root.configure(bg='#ff8080')
root.geometry("750x550")

def arrays():
    v = IntVar()
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    def close():
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        arrays()

    titleFrame = Frame(root)
    titleFrame.grid(row=0)

    radioFrame = Frame(root)
    radioFrame.grid(padx=350, pady=100)

    inputFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#ff8080')
    inputFrame.grid()

    buttonFrame = Frame(root)
    buttonFrame.grid()

    Title = tk.Label(titleFrame, bg='#ff8080', text="Enter The Number of Elements In The Array", font="-weight bold")
    Title.grid()

    global NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES
    NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES = Entry(inputFrame)
    NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, ipadx=10, ipady=10,padx=10, pady=10)

    if NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES == int:
        print("Working")
    else:
        print("Please Enter a Integer Value")

    global num
    num = 0

    #global NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES
    #NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES = simpledialog.askinteger("Please Enter", "Enter The Number of Elements In The Array")

    global alist
    alist = []

    for i in range (0, NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES):
        num = simpledialog.askinteger("Please Enter" ,"Enter The Entries In Array Element " + str(i))
        alist = alist + [ num ]

    calculate = ttk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Proceed", command=entries)
    calculate.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E + S, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

arrays()
root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to make it so when a user inputs a integer number into the Entry input box it stores into the variable NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES. After it stores it, it then proceeds to use the value in the further conditionals.

But I am getting an issue when I try to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not an integer. `NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES` is of type `<class 'tkinter.Entry'>`.

The usual way to do this is to associate the entry with a `StringVar()` which will reflect whatever is typed into the entry.

The text entered into an entry is still text so you'll have to convert it to `int` explicitly.

See [The Tkinter Entry Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).